# Undefined variable outside of a function

Tags: node.js, socket.io, p5.js

I have a code that using a node.js and socket.io.

When i wrote this code in this way;

Server side:

```js
function display(width, height){
  this.width = width * 2;
  this.height = height * 2;
}

function position(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function initialize(){
  for(var x = circlePosition.length; x < circleCount; x++){
    circlePosition[x] = new position(Math.random() * (resolution.width - (-resolution.width)) + (-resolution.width), Math.random() * (resolution.height - (-resolution.height)) + (-resolution.height));
    
  }
}

socket.on('display',
      function(data) {
        resolution = new display(data.width, data.height);
        initialize();
        io.sockets.emit('positioning', circlePosition);
      });
```

Client side;

```js
var position;
var resolution = {
  width: 1366,
  height: 666
 };

 socket.emit('display', resolution);

 socket.on('positioning',
  function(data){
   position = data;
  });
 console.log(position); // <---
```

The position variable is undefined, but if i use this code on the client side

```js
var position;
var resolution = {
  width: 1366,
  height: 666
 };

 socket.emit('display', resolution);

 socket.on('positioning',
  function(data){
   position = data;
      console.log(position); // <---
  });
```

It has value. Why I can't use the value sent using socket.io outside the function?

Comment: did you see the log of data?

Comment: @MuhammadAli yes, at first set of code it was undefined, on the second set, it has its value.

Comment: oh sorry i didnt notice your second last snippet

Comment: you can pass on function

Comment: Please learn how to properly format/indent your code here.  Note how I've made it properly formatted in my answer.

Comment: I give you a solution based the information that you provided. and you gave me a negative mark? why? at least give me an explanation

Comment: @Teocci i didn't give a downvote, i don't give a downvote to anyone who tried and made an effort to help me. I'm not that kind of person.

Comment: There is apparently a serial downvoter loose on this questions and these answers and not a single comment as to why.  That is not a very appropriate way to use this site.  Unfortunately, stackoverflow provides no way of knowing who did it or any way to ask them why.  I'll just leave a comment here and hope they see it and provide some feedback on why all the downvotes so people can improve their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about exactly what this line of code is doing:

```
socket.on('positioning',
   function(data){
      position = data;
   });
```

This is setting up a **callback function** that will be called when you get a `positioning` event. But note that this function isn't called yet! It will be called sometime in the future. This is just the **initialization** of the function.

If you put a `console.log()` call **after** the initialization of the callback function, that `console.log()` will happen **before** the function is actually called! That's why the variable is undefined, because the variable has not been set yet!

If you put the `console.log()` call **inside** the callback function, then you're guaranteeing that it happens **after** the callback function is called, so the variable is set.

It might be more clear if you don't use an inline function:

```
var position;
var resolution = {
        width: 1366,
        height: 666
    };

socket.emit('display', resolution);
socket.on('positioning', myCallback);
console.log(position);

function myCallback(data){
   position = data;
}
```

This is exactly what your code is doing, except now I'm using a named function instead of an inline function. But now it's more obvious that the callback has not been called yet when `console.log()` is executed.

Comment: So basically i should put a console.log inside the function to be able to read the initiation?

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate Yep. I just edited my answer to include another example that might make it more obvious.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate My edit was not meant to be a solution. It was meant to highlight why your code is behaving the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

In the first client scenario, your `console.log(position)` is running BEFORE your event handler has run.  Remember, when you do `socket.on(...)`, you are just registering an event handler that may be called sometime in the future.  The rest of your code continues to run.  So, the next line after registering your event handler is the `console.log()` statement.  Since the event handler has not yet been triggered (it's registered, but no event has yet happened to make it run), `position` has no value yet.

So, looking at your code:

```
socket.on('positioning', function(data) {
    position = data;
});
// position has not yet been set because the above event handler
// has not yet been triggered
console.log(position);
```

The ONLY safe place to use the data sent by the `positioning` event is INSIDE the callback which is exactly what you do in the other scenario where things work properly:

```
socket.on('positioning', function(data) {
    // use the data here
    console.log(data);
});
```

FYI, this is a fundamental concept of event driven programming.  You register event handlers that are called sometime in the future.  You often have no idea when they will be called so you have to just handle the data they provide inside the event handler when they are called.

Comment: How? but i wrote the assigning of value before i wrote the console.log

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate - No.  All you did was register an event handler that will be called sometime in the future.  The code in that function has NOT yet run.  This is the basis of event driven programming which is how node.js works.

Comment: So basically i should put a console.log inside the function to be able to read the initiation?

Comment: I didn't vote down to your answer my friend. Thank you for this answer, going to try this.

Comment: **Why the downvote?**  Downvoters, please explain your downvote so we have the opportunity to improve our answer and address your issue since this site is about creating the best answers for the OP we can.  As best I can tell, everything in this answer is technically correct.  Please explain what you think it is missing to deserve a downvote!

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate - As my answer says (please study what I've already written), the ONLY safe place to use the data provided by an event callback is INSIDE the callback itself or in a function you call from inside that callback and pass the data to.

Comment: But I triggered it on the server side? Look at the code.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate when you use `io.sockets.emit('positioning', circlePosition);` in the server side, what are you doing there is sending the data to the clients. Now in your client implementation you have the `socket.on(positioning, ...)` this part captures "the event" `positioning` and get the `circlePostion` in the `data` variable. But this variable only works inside of the 'socket.on(..` function. So we give you some alternatives to solve that issue..

Comment: Is there anyway i could copy the value of data to the local variable of the client? I need it so i could use it outside of the function.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate - Whatever you want to do with that incoming value, you need to do it when the data arrives.  There is NO other way to know when there is new data unless you do something with it when it arrives.  That's how event driven programming works.  You can copy it to some higher scoped variable if you want, but NONE of your other code knows when there's a new value there.  That's why you generally don't want to do that.  You need to think of your code as event driven.  OK, new value arrives, what do I want to do with the new value (probably display it for the user).

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate - You triggered it on the server side, long AFTER your `console.log()` statement.  Event driven programming is all about timing and the only way you KNOW the timing is INSIDE the event callback, not outside that callback.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.on()` is an asynchronously call -- this means your will only call the anonymous function *after* `data` has been fully loaded from the server.

---

Note: You may use `position` from another code that is *outside* the anonymous function *after* the anonymous function has been run (Yeah, ,  you will need to wait to access it). But how? Well, the best way to do this is to put the dependent code into its own function, and then call that function from within the callback function like in this example:

```js
var position;
var resolution = {
  width: 1366,
  height: 666
};

socket.emit('display', resolution);

socket.on('positioning',
  function(data) {
    loadPosition(); // <---
  }
);

function loadPosition() {
  position = data;
  console.log(position); // ... do whatever you need to do with postion here
}
```

Comment: mhm someone trying to get badges probably.

Comment: @Teocci - What badges to you earn by downvoting?

Comment: I'm going to up this answer to cancel the anonymous down vote. Thank you for the effort to try to solve my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you object/value received from callBack response

```
var position;
var resolution = {
    width: 1366,
    height: 666
};

socket.emit('display', resolution);

socket.on('positioning',
    function(data){
        position = data;
    positionUpdate()
    });

function positionUpdate(){
console.log(position); 
}
```

Comment: I didn't give the negative mark, I'll going to try this good, I think it looks great.

Comment: I'm going to up this answer to cancel the anonymous down vote. Thank you for the effort to try to solve my case.

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't yet solve your problem, try this. This is what I did.

```
var resolution = {
    width: 1366,
    height: 666
};

socket.emit('display', resolution);

socket.on('positioning', function(data){
    getPosition(data, position);
});

var getPosition = function(data, callback){
   callback(data);
}

var position = function(data){
   console.log(data); // <--
}
```